# If light had mass

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, estimation

Is there any way to know how fast would light be if it had a mass? Something like  0.000000178536 kg. At least a formula to help estimate it would help, i asked chatgpt and it said ''E = mc²
E = (0.00000000178536 kg) * (299,792,458 m/s)²'' but couldn't find a source of how accurate it is. I am also wanna curios for how fast would the slowest electro magnetic wave would be cuz chatgpt also said ''mass wouldn't affect it'' but couldn't find a source

Comment: Why would light having a mass lead to it having a specific speed? You have a certain mass - how fast are *you*?

Comment: You're asking ChatGPT about physics? Why not ask your cat, it'd be cheaper

Comment: @ACuriousMind i thought light being maselss is why it is so fast, that whar many sources i seem say

Comment: If an object has mass, its speed can be anywhere in the range $0\le v<c$.

Comment: *i asked chatgpt and it said…* So ChatGPT added those extra zeros after the decimal point?

Answer (score 3):

The name for a particle of light is a photon and the current experimental bound on the mass of a photon is
$$m < 10^{-18}\,\, \mathrm{eV}/c^2 = 1.78\times 10^{-54}\,\,\mathrm{kg},$$
according to the [Particle Data Group (it's the gauge boson called "gamma" in the table)](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/listings/contents_listings.html).

This is **much** smaller than your $1.78\times 10^{-9}$ kg.  Theoretically photons have no mass.  It's impossible to tell if something is exactly zero with an experiment because all measurements have an associated uncertainty.
The experimental bound says that when we try to measure the mass of a photon we find that it is consistent with zero, but with an uncertainty of  about $10^{-54}$ kg.  If a photon's mass were more than $10^{-54}$ kg, we would have noticed.

If a photon had mass, you would calculate its speed the same way as any other particle.  For fast things like photons, we need to use special relativity.  The energy of a photon depends on its frequency.  High frequency X-rays and gamma-rays have more energy then lower frequency visible light and even lower frequency radio waves.  The more kinetic energy something has the faster it goes, so high energy gamma-rays would be faster than visible light.

The energy of a photon is
$$E = hf,$$
where $h$ is Planck's constant and $f$ is the frequency.  The energy of a massive moving particle in special relativity is
$$E = \gamma mc^2 = \frac{m c^2}{\sqrt{1- v^2/c^2}},$$
where $m$ is the mass, $c$ is the universal speed limit (the usual speed of light), and $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor), which is expanded out in terms of velocity, $v$, in the last part.

Putting the two equations together you can solve for $v$ as a function of $f$ and $m$:
$$v = c\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{mc^2}{hf}\right)^2}.$$

In the limit that light is massless, $m\rightarrow 0$, and it travels at the usual speed $c$.  Higher frequency light travels faster because $\frac{mc^2}{hf}$ gets smaller.  There would be a cutoff where $mc^2 > hf$, giving a negative number under the square root and setting a minimum allowed frequency for light.  If $mc^2 = hf$ then $v=0$, and the light wouldn't move.

So if light had $m = 10^{-54}$ kg, then the minimum frequency would be about $10^{-4}$ Hz, and visible light would move at about $0.999 999 999 999 999 999  999 999 999 999 999 999 6 c$ (that's $36$ $9$'s before the final $6$!).

Of course none of these effects have been observed, and as best we can tell light is massless.

Comment: thanks but kinda confused on one thing if it doesn't bother answering this one too, how exactly you got 10^-4 hz

Comment: That's from solving the inequality for the cutoff frequency $mc^2 > hf$.

Comment: ohh alright so bassically doing the mass i mentioned in the op multiplied by c^2 > planck constant multiplied by frequency or what?

Answer (score 1):

By light having mass, I assume you mean giving photons mass. In that case, in terms of velocity, photons would behave the same as any other particle with mass, with their energy given by:
$E^2 = m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2$.

In the above equation, I'm using $c$ as the speed of light, this is the universal constant that's set to 299,792,458 m/s, so I'm assuming this universal speed limit would remain the same, and the speed of photons travelling in a vacuum would be less than what it currently is.

Giving mass to photons would have massive effects on the electromagnetic interaction though. There are lots of other issues that would need to be resolved with giving mass to photons, but that goes into electroweak theory.

Answer (score 0):

If photons have mass, they travel at:

$$ \frac {pc^2} E = \frac{\gamma m vc^2}{\gamma mc^2} = v$$

With $c=1$:

$$ v = \frac p E = \frac p {\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}} $$

and with $\hbar=1$:

$$\frac E p =\frac{\omega} k = \frac{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}{k} = v_{phase} > c$$

or:

$$ \omega(k) = \sqrt{k^2+m^2} $$

so that the group velocity is:

$$ v_{group} = \frac{d\omega}{dk}= \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} = \frac k {\omega} < c$$

So there would be dispersion in classical EM propagation.

The Coulomb potential would look like:

$$ V(r) \propto \frac{e^{-r/L}}{r}$$

with the characteristic length scale:

$$ L = \frac{mc^2}{\hbar c} = \frac{mc^2}{197\, {\rm MeV \cdot fm}} \gt 21{\,\rm Billion\  Light\ Years}$$

for $m < 10^{-18}$ eV.